# ng-show if input checked an element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanna show an icon when an item checked in input list.

```
<span ng-show="ctrl.filter[year]" class="fa fa-close"></span>
```

And my input:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.filter[year]" id='year{{$index}}' class='chk-btn styled-checkbox' />
```

When I checked the page, its not working, I cannot see close button if I selected an item. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also note the other attributes needed for a checkbox in angular docs

Comment: Please post controller code and show what is `year`

Comment: @J.Doe Well your code seems fine, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jbceqzue/) is a fiddle, replicate the issue and share back